# CORS to allow remote embedding of javascript

Tags: javascript, php, cors

I have a javascript widget that can be embedded from a remote server (Eg. http://aaa.bbb.ccc)

My javascript (a simple alert('hello')) is created by a php script, and when it is executed I send header

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://aaa.bbb.ddd");
echo "alert('hello')";
```

I expected that my javascript can't be executed on remote host but the alert is showed.

What's wrong?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are no restrictions on loading scripts from different origins.

The Same Origin Policy prevents JavaScript from reading from different origins.

CORS is a way to *relax* the Same Origin Policy to allow JS to read data from different origins.

CORS can't add additional restrictions above what the Same Origin Policy applies by default.

---

Consider writing the JS to check the value of `location` and throwing an exception if it is unacceptable.